# Remix.run and Fusion chart

Tags: reactjs, fusioncharts, remix.run, react-fusioncharts

Using `react-fusioncharts` in a [Remix.run](https://remix.run) app doesn't seem to work? Any workarounds?

`ReactFC.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Column2D, GammelTheme)`

I'm getting this error:

`ReferenceError: document is not defined`

It makes sense since Remix use SSR, but even if I use this safe guard it fails (recommended approach from [Remix docs](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/constraints#initializing-browser-only-apis)):

```
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
    ReactFC.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Column2D, GammelTheme)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The component needs to be wrapped inside a `ClientOnly` component from [`remix-utils`](https://github.com/sergiodxa/remix-utils#clientonly). This way, the component will render only on the client and will not be server-rendered.

```
// components/chart.jsx
import * as ReactFS from 'fusionchart'

export default function Chart() {
  // this component will only render on the client
  // and will not be server rendered
  return (
    {/* fusion chart components */}
  )
}

// routes/index.tsx
import {ClientOnly} from 'remix-utils'
import Chart from '~/components/chart'

export default function() {
  return (
    <ClientOnly fallback={<LoadingSkeleton />}
      {() => <Chart />}
    </ClientOnly>
  )
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :/ I'm not sure if thats specfic FusionChart issue. Still the same error: ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> {path}/node_modules/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js:13:758)

Comment: rename `chart.jsx` in the solution to `chart.client.jsx`. FusionChart is probably trying to use `document` on the initial import before it is even rendered. `.client` suffix will tell Remix not to import it on the server